# how to move any svg imgae rather than MarkupsCore as markup on viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to place some 2d svg images on the viewer, i was able to place them as using loadmarkups with the help of svg string but they are not movable . **i need to make them movable**. please help me in regards with this.
any help will be appericiated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I modified the sample I pointed out previously to work with SVG files: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/stamp-markup-using-svg-file

Comment: thanks to you very much i will try it and revert back. Thanks Again!

Comment: thanks for the great help @Adam Nagy , its working very fine for me.

Comment: Hi @AdamNagy i have tried the things you shared its loading correctly as markup but i got one issue as when i'm saving it as svg string and then try to load again using loadmarkups it loading but after i update it with adding more markups in layer and save it gives me error and will not load. the reason i got to know is the multiple g tags  when i removed group tag its loading but lost its tranformations and metadata_element is also lost can you please have a look into this

Comment: It is mentioned in both articles that "The extension cannot currently deserialize custom markups from an SVG; you would have to parse the markup manually" But I don't see an error: https://youtu.be/h-AzhrVEBDY